# Is it possible to drive a power piezoelectric in lower frequency than its own frequency?

Tags: driver, series, piezo, piezoelectricity

I am driving a piezo transducer simply by an inductor **series** with piezo.
the resonant frequency of the piezo is about **40KHz** and I designed a **20KHz** transducer.
I'm giving a **pulse voltage** (using a class E driver) to drive this series circuit
and by turning the value of L(inductor), I force the piezo and L to **resonate** at 20KHz frequency and get a high voltage on piezo electrodes.

My questions are:

1. Why does nobody mention this method to drive a power piezo?
2. Is this method damages the piezo?
3. Without considering the efficiency, is it alright to drive a piezo in other frequencies?

Comment: If the piezo is low Q, sure (its frequency response is wide rather than not narrow).

Comment: It'll be very inefficient unless you decrease the transducer's natural resonant frequency.

Comment: Small 'k' for kilo. A KHz is a kelvin-hertz. Capitals matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about maximizing the output **amplitude** when lightly damped then you can operate away from mechanical resonance.

Operating a resonant transducer at it's mechanical resonant frequency allows relatively small drive voltage and current to result in a lot of motion (strain).

Efficiency aside, since there are limits to drive voltage, whether it's supplied by a coil or an amplifier, operating away from resonance limits the maximum output amplitude. From [this](https://piezo.com/pages/piezoelectric-generators) website.

[image]